# Ping Docker Container from another machine in the network

Tags: networking, ping, docker

I have created a docker container and tried pinging www.google.com within the bash of the container and it works. Also I tried pinging the container from the host - it works perfectly fine.

But when I try to ping the container from a external system in the network, it gives me a request timed out exception.

I am planning to install a tomcat webserver on a container and allow other containers to access the application deployed in the server. Would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot ping a Docker container from an external host by default (to do so, you would have to ensure that the Docker network bridge -docker0- has an IP Address, and you would have to configure routes on your other hosts to use you Docker host as a gateway for the bridge address range).

By default, any service running inside a Docker container is not "Published" (Docker terminology) and cannot be reached from outside. You have to explicitly define/allow the services you want to be published when you run your container.

For example, to publish your container's Tomcat app (supposing it is configured to listen on port **8080**) to port **80** on the host, you would run your container using the `-p` option :

```
    docker run -d -p 80:8080 my-tomcat-image:tag
```

But if you only want to access Tomcat from other containers on the same host, you don't need to configure anything.

Comment: Tried to add a route from host1 to the docker container network inside of host2. Is this possible? I tried to add the static route on host1 with the 172.17.x.x(docker network on host2) and put the gateway as host2. I dont get any packets to host2. Is there something I need to look into?


172.17.0.0      172.31.69.211   255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 eth0 is the route on host1 pointing to host2 ip address.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to accomplish this without the need to configure routes on your other hosts, at least using **Podman**, not sure about Docker.
You can use CNI plugin **ipvlan** for this:

```
{
  "cniVersion": "0.4.0",
  "name": "podman",
  "plugins": [
    {
      "type": "ipvlan",
      "master": "baremetal",
      "bridge": "cni-podman0",
      "isGateway": false,
      "isDefaultGateway": false,
      "ipMasq": false,
      "hairpinMode": false,
      "promiscMode": true,
      "ipam": {
        "type": "host-local",
        "ranges": [
          [
            {
              "subnet": "192.168.216.0/21"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you just create the containers with IPs in the subnet (I am assuming 192.168.216.0/21 is the subnet of the external systems in your network):

```
podman run --ip 192.168.216.201 -d quay.io/frrouting/frr
```

This containers will be reachable from your external systems (not by the host running the container though).

Answer (score 0):

I installed docker desktop in windows 10.  I faced similar challenge to ping the container from windows 10. Since the docker host cannot reach the linux containers([Known limitations, use cases, and workarounds](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/)), here is a way to reach out the container ip.  We can ping via vEthernet WSL ip to Docker Gateway to Container ip.

**Solution:**

1. type "ipconfig /all" in host command prompt.
2. find the ip of "Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL)"

[vEthernet (WSL) ip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgC1h.png)

[Containers running:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Eox.png)

[Ping thru vEthernet (WSL) ip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLBA8.png)

Similar to the above, other containers are also pinging from windows 10.

Hope this helps for windows users.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I edited the content with little bit clarity.