# How to access guest IP in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am making my first steps with docker-compose. I created a very basic docker-compose.yml file with this content:

```
version: '2'
  services:
    webserver:
      build: ./docker/webserver
      image: runwaytest_web
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
      volumes:
        - /myhome/Docker/simple-docker/www:/var/www/html
        - /myhome/Docker/simple-docker/symfony3:/var/www/symfony3
      links:
        - mysql

     mysql:
       # mysql stuff
```

I also have a very basic Dockerfile in `./docker/webserver`. Servers are created correctly. If I ssh to the container, apache is running and the config file is correct.

When I inspect my container from the host, the IP is 172.18.0.3, but I can't ping it, and virtual host for symfony3 does not work (actually I can't neither reach the base http-document folder in `/var/www`).

I am using Docker for Mac.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24149795/99189 for why you can't ping your container.  In general, don't expect to be able to do that.  The only network access you have to the container is through the ports that you expose, 80 and 443 in this case.

From the perspective of running this in a docker container and using virtual hosts, you'll need your http client to send a `Host:` header when making requests to `localhost:80`/`localhost:443`.

Assuming you are testing with a browser, and that your vhost is `user3174311.com`, try the following:

- add the line `127.0.0.1 user3174311.com` to your `/etc/hosts`
- visit [user3174311.com](http://user3174311.com) in your browser

This is what should be happening:

- browser looks up `user3174311.com` in `/etc/hosts` and resolves it to `127.0.0.1`
- browser sends an http request with a `Host: user3174311.com` header to `127.0.0.1:80`
- docker is listening on this address and forwards the connection to port 80 in your container
- apache sees the request, looks at the `Host:` header and determines the correct virtual host to use

After that, it depends on your apache/symphony3 configuration.  You'll have to post more details if it's not working.

Comment: thanks for your answer, of course I added the ip in my /etc/hosts file, and I also created a virtual host on the guest. I am not a networking expert, but I expected to be able to ping the IP if I want the browser on the host to access the vhost on the guest? this is what I do usually when working with vagrant but it now seems everybody is moving to docker...

Comment: Which ip did you add?  It should not be that of the docker container, because you can't route to it.  It should be `localhost`.  Docker is listening on `localhost:80` and `localhost:443` and forwarding the traffic to the container.

Comment: ok I got it now, thanks. So how can I point the browser to a vhost I defined inside the container?

Comment: In `/etc/hosts` add: `127.0.0.1 thevhost`.  In the browser, visit `http://thevhost`.  The browser (after reading the hosts file) will initiate a connection to `127.0.0.1:80` and send an http request with a header `Host: thevhost`.  Docker will accept this connection and forward it to port 80 of the container, where the request will be received by apache, which will interpret the `Host` header to identify the vhost.